# passwordless ssh ubuntu in script

Tags: shell, ubuntu, ssh

I have a passwordless ssh setup for ubuntu. It works fine, I can give ssh commands from the command line. But if I have a script that contains an ssh command, it still asks for my password. 
Example of command in script:

```
ssh ubuntu@localhost 'mkdir -p mydir'
```

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Thanks,
Serban

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you mean is:

> I can `ssh` to my server and run this script without a password as my own public key is in the server's `authorized_keys` file, but when I run the script and it `ssh`'s to itself, it asks for a password. Why?

If so, the answer is that the server does not your have your private key, so the entry in the `authorized_keys` file is insufficient.

You can test this by seeing whether *when logged into the server* `ssh ubuntu@localhost` asks for a password.

Either:

1. copy your private key to the server (in general a bad idea); or
2. generate a new private/public keypair on the server (with `ssh-keygen`), and put the public element of *that* keypair into `authorized_keys`.

Answer (score 0):

In the server:

```
cd /home/ubuntu/.ssh/
cat id_rsa.pub >> authorized_keys
```

where id_rsa is your public key in the client from which you want to access the server.

Comment: I think OP has already done that (that's what he means by *'I have a passwordless ssh setup for ubuntu. It works fine, I can give ssh commands from the command line.'* - but I agree it's not entirely clear.

Comment: @abligh uhm... anyhow, this may be useful for anyone else :-)